# ValueError: could not convert string to float, how to solve?

Tags: valueerror

Hi I am pretty new to python, I was given a script and had to create a regression model from a dataset that I chose. I converted all the categorical variables to continuous variables in order to run a linear regression model.
Data before converting categorical to continuous variable

[image]

Data after converting cataegorical to continuous variable
[image]

Code I am using

```
import scipy.stats as stats
for i in range(len(col_lst2)-1):
  fvalue, pvalue = stats.f_oneway(df.iloc[:,i],df.iloc[:,-1])
  print("For "+col_lst2[i]+ ", "+ "F value stands at " + str(fvalue) + " and" + " P value stands at " + str(pvalue))
```

I am getting this error. can someone tell me what is wrong with the data or the code?
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeyC6.png)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Ideal'

I am trying to get p values and f value

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

You have a text in one of your column and you are trying to perform numerical analysis on it.

Convert that into a numerical value first. Use pd.get_dummies